# Is it possible to inherit from class given as parameter?

Tags: python, class, inheritance

I have several classes which I treat like a containers for my data (figure representation). They all have same `@staticmethod`s e.g. `get_edges()`, `get_vertices()`. I want to import specified figure class by given parameter. What I do now is:

```
class Figure:
    def __init__(self, figure_type):
        exec('import figures.' + figure_type.lower())
        self.element = eval('figures.' + figure_type.lower() + '.' + figure_type)()

    def create(self, vertices):
        glBegin(GL_LINES)
        for edge in self.element.get_edges():
            for vertex in edge:
                glColor3fv((0.5,0,0))
                glVertex3fv(vertices[vertex])
        glEnd()

class Cube:

    @staticmethod
    def get_edges():
        return ((0, 1),(0, 3),(0, 4),(2, 1),(2, 3),(2, 7),(6, 3),(6, 4),(6, 7),(5, 1),(5, 4),(5, 7))
```

I wonder if there is a way to get something like:

```
class Figure(figure_type):
    def __init__(self, figure_type):
```

To be able to use just e.g. `self.get_edges()` instead of `self.element.get_edges()`. How can I get it? Is it even possible?

Comment: In OOP you would use a Factory pattern to create Objects: https://python-3-patterns-idioms-test.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Factory.html#simple-factory-method

Comment: Why have you chosen this *scheme*? Does `Figure` have methods common to all `figure_type`'s and each `figure_type` has specific edges and vertices methods? Do the objects need to be `Figure` instances for some reason?

Comment: @wwii Yes, `Figure` contains methods applied to each `figure_type`. `figure_type` contains only methods which returns `set`s with edges, vertices or surfaces to draw them in `OpenGL` in `Figure` class. Why have I chosen it? Well, it seems to have good readability for me and maybe in future I can add some specific methods to each figure, but honestly speaking I'm beginner, so probably I could do better design. At the moment I try to follow given links in answers, but those concepts seems to me a little bit advanced.

Comment: Sounds like a `figure_type` could be a subclass of `Figure`.

Comment: @wwii So better would be to create classes like e.g. `class Cube(Figure)` filled with `@staticmethod`s - `get_edges()` , vertices, surfaces and then use e.g. `Cube().create()` using `create()` function defined in `Figure`? Some figures will be never created. It depends on game mode. So I should stick to `exec('import figures.' + figure_type.lower())` inside function which uses `Cube`?

Comment: Just trying to understand your purpose: @MauriceMeyer may be correct or `hspandher's` answer or something else.

Comment: @Ethr, get rid of `exec` and use `importlib` instead. Using Factory pattern might be easier than metaclasses as stated by hspandher (but metclasses are more sophisticated and fun to play with).

Comment: A better design would be to simply put all your figure types in a *single* module. Defining separate modules like `figure.cube` and `figure.whatever` do anything useful, and complicates precisely what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your design looks like you are making [mixins](https://stackoverflow.com/a/547714/2823755). Here is a class factory toy example that can produces the mixins dynamically.

---

figures.py

```
data = ((0, 1),(0, 3),(0, 4),(2, 1),(2, 3),(2, 7),(6, 3))

class FT:
    @staticmethod
    def ge():
        return data

class FT1:
    @staticmethod
    def ge():
        return [(x*x,y*y) for x,y in data]

def compose(ftype):
    '''Returns a class composed of F and ftype.'''
    return type(f'F_{ftype.__name__}',(F,ftype),{})
```

---

some_module.py:

```
import importlib

class F:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 'foo'
    def a(self):
        s = '|'.join(f'{thing}' for thing in self.ge())
        return s
    def b(self):
        return 'baz'

def compose(ftype):
    cls = getattr(importlib.import_module('figures'),ftype)
    return type(f'F_{ftype}',(F,cls),{})


z = compose('FT')()
y = compose('FT1')()
```

---

Both objects have the same `b` methods.

```
>>> z.b(), y.b()
('baz', 'baz')
```

Both have the same `a` methods using data from specific `ge` methods

```
>>> print(z.a())
(0, 1)|(0, 3)|(0, 4)|(2, 1)|(2, 3)|(2, 7)|(6, 3)
>>> y.a()
'(0, 1)|(0, 9)|(0, 16)|(4, 1)|(4, 9)|(4, 49)|(36, 9)'
```

Each object has specific `ge` methods

```
>>> z.ge()
((0, 1), (0, 3), (0, 4), (2, 1), (2, 3), (2, 7), (6, 3))
>>> y.ge()
[(0, 1), (0, 9), (0, 16), (4, 1), (4, 9), (4, 49), (36, 9)]
>>>
```

`z` and `y` are instances of different classes.

```
>>> z.__class__, y.__class__
(<class '__main__.F_FT'>, <class '__main__.F_FT1'>)
>>>
```

Multiple instances of a composed class.

```
>>> One = compose(FT)
>>> q,r,s = One(),One(),One()
>>> q,r,s
(<__main__.F_FT object at 0x0000000003163860>,
 <__main__.F_FT object at 0x000000000D334198>,
 <__main__.F_FT object at 0x000000000D334828>)
>>>
```

---

If *everything* is in the same module then compose becomes

```
def compose(ftype):
    return type(f'F_{ftype.__name__}',(F,ftype),{})

z = compose(FT)
y = compose(FT1)
```

---

[What is the difference between a mixin and inheritance?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27907511/2823755)

---

Similar solution using an abstract base class. - G cannot be instantiated unless
`ge` is overridden.

```
import importlib
import abc

class G(abc.ABC):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 'foo'
    def a(self):
        s = '|'.join(f'{thing}' for thing in self.ge())
        return s
    def b(self):
        return 'baz'

    @staticmethod
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def ge():
        pass

# either of these work
def new(ftype):
    cls = getattr(importlib.import_module('figures'),ftype)
    return type(cls.__name__,(cls,G),{})
#def new(ftype):
#    cls = getattr(importlib.import_module('figures'),ftype)
#    return type(cls.__name__,(G,),{'ge':staticmethod(cls.ge)})
#usage
# A = new('FT')
```

---

Similar except the specific *static* methods are just plain functions and using the ABC from above

```
def FT_ge():
    return ((0, 1),(0, 3),(0, 4),(2, 1),(2, 3),(2, 7),(6, 3))
def other_new(f):
    return type(f.__name__.split('_')[0],(G,),{'ge':staticmethod(f)})
# usage
# B = other_new(FT_ge)
```

Comment: I have no idea  of any possible adverse consequences - feel free to weigh in with criticisms or edits.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `importlib.import_module` to import the module. However, it would be recommended to inherit those classes from a base class that uses a metaclass to keep track of it subclasses and maps them, say, in a dictionary. Then you can use this base class as a abstraction to interact with all child classes [Track subclasses in python](https://avacariu.me/articles/2016/using-a-metaclass-to-keep-track-of-subclasses)

Comment: Can you show a working toy example mimicking OP's examples?